# node-mysql, cannot connect to mysql database on centos server?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, express, nginx

I have a node-mysql-express-angular.js application with a standard login & registration feature. I have this project running as expected on my localhost. However, when I deploy the project on my centos 6.7 server It cannot connect the the mysql database. Here is the sql.js file..

```
var connection = require('express-myconnection');
var mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports = function(app){
    app.use(
        connection(mysql,{
            host    : 'localhost.localdomain',
            user    : 'root',
            password: 'password',
            port    :  3306,
            database: 'database_name'
        }, 'request')
    );
};
```

I know I have the mysql settings correct because when in mysql I've done the 'select @@hostname;' and 'select @@port;' commands to get the current settings.

The error I'm seeing is a 'GET http://0.0.0.0/users 404 (Not Found) - angular.js:9827' (fake IP of course)

I've tried playing with nginx conf settings and using an express-router but cannot fix this issue. I really think its a database issue because when you turn off mysql servers on the localhost it reproduces the same error on my local machine. Any help is greatly appreciated because I'm out of ideas.. Thanks!

Comment: Returning a 404 for a database failure is unusual and sort of suspect, but you said your local dev does the same thing when MySQL's turned off so I'll accept that.  Given that, you then need to figure out if MySQL has the appropriate grants for root@localhost, and if that differs from root@127.0.0.1. Connect to MySQL from the command line first and `SHOW GRANTS`.

Comment: | Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*reallylongpassword' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: this is what it shows, I tried using the '*reallylongpassword' instead of my current mysql user password. still the same error..